# How to make keyboard usable in perl debugger (and get rid of control characters)

Tags: shell, perl, debugging

In all my Perl installations, on very different machines using different versions of Perl (up to v5.36, which is the latest at the time of writing), upon invoking the Perl debugger using `perl -d SomeModule.pm`, I have trouble using the keyboard as I am used to in the shell. Readline seems broken, as if sshing to a host without exporting `TERM=xterm`, first.
`up` prints `^[[A` instead of accessing a history, `home` prints `^[[H` instead of moving the cursor, `end` prints `^[[F`, etc.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

See https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug#Readline-Support-/-History-in-the-Debugger

> ### Readline Support / History in the Debugger
>
> As shipped, the only command-line history supplied is a simplistic one
> that checks for leading exclamation points. However, if you install
> the Term::ReadKey and Term::ReadLine modules from CPAN (such as
> Term::ReadLine::Gnu, Term::ReadLine::Perl, ...) you will have full
> editing capabilities much like those GNU *readline*(3) provides. Look
> for these in the *modules/by-module/Term* directory on CPAN. These do
> not support normal **vi** command-line editing, however.
>
> A rudimentary command-line completion is also available, including
> lexical variables in the current scope if the `PadWalker` module is
> installed.
>
> Without Readline support you may see the symbols "^[[A", "^[[C",
> "^[[B", "^[[D"", "^H", ... when using the arrow keys and/or the
> backspace key.